# How to get the real line number of a selection?

Tags: region, line-numbers, doom

I am trying to figure out the line numbers referring to the actual selection. What I came up with is something like this

```lisp
(let ((start (line-number-at-pos (region-beginning)))
      (end (line-number-at-pos (region-end))))
  (ignore))
```

But if I select whole lines then `(region-end)` returns the position of the beginning of the next line instead of the end of the currently selected line.

If I am selecting anything but complete lines then the `(region-end)` function works correctly. Is there a way to get the real line number or to figure out whether the user is selecting complete lines or not?

I would like to differentiate between these those:

#### Selecting lines

[image: selecting lines]

Expected output `1` and `2`.

#### Selecting blocks

[image: selecting blocks]

Expected output `1` and `3`.

Comment: `bolp` tells you whether point is at the beginning of a line.

Comment: How would you like to differentiate between those two? Your original description implied that the range of lines should be 1-2 in both cases.

Comment: In the first case it should be `1` and `2` and in the second case it should be `1` and `3`.

Comment: Your version does exactly what you specify in these two cases - so what is the question?

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not and that is my problem. In both cases my version returns `1` and `3` for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check if region-end and the beginning of the line at region-end are the same position, and if so, subtract one from the end line number? Something like this perhaps:

```el
(defun test-linenos ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((rend (region-end))
         (startl (line-number-at-pos (region-beginning)))
         (endl (line-number-at-pos rend))
         (real-endl (if (= rend (save-excursion (goto-char rend) (beginning-of-line) (point)))
                        (- endl 1)
                      endl)))
    (message (format "%d %d" startl real-endl))))
```

You can mark a region and call the function with `M-x test-linenos` to check what line numbers it produces. Of course, only the calculation is important: the function is just scaffolding for testing.

Note that I used a `let*` form, since I wanted to calculate the region end once, but use its value later when binding the following variables.
That is explained in [Local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html#Local-Variables) in the Emacs Lisp manual.

BTW, your `let` is badly formed: see the reference above for the proper format:

```
(let ((var val)
      (var val)
      ...
      (var val))
   ...use the variables...)
```

Comment: That is the only idea I also came up with, but I thought that there must be a better way to handle this. I intentionally left out the actions from the `(let)` because it didn't matter for the question.

Comment: My problem with this solution is that if somebody wants to intentionally select the first character of the next line then I cannot tell that. Isn't there a way to figure out whether the use is selecting multiple lines or characters?

Comment: Sure you can: read the description of [point](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Point.html#Point) - think of it as being **between** two characters, so if your cursor is on the second character of the line, the region includes the first character, If it is on the first character of the line, the region ends after the newline on the previous line.